# Vue 3 composition API get value from RefImpl

Tags: vue.js, getlocation

I utilized the useGeolocation function from @vueuse/core to access the user's current location. However, upon attempting to retrieve the latitude and longitude coordinates, it returned an Infinity value. What could be causing this issue? How can it return real value?

Code:

```
    <script setup>
    import { onBeforeMount, onMounted, ref } from "vue";
    import { useGeolocation } from "@vueuse/core";
    const { coords, locatedAt, error, resume, pause } = useGeolocation();

    const form = ref({
        coords: null,
    })

    onMounted(() => {
        form.value.coords = {
            latitude: coords.value.latitude,
            longitude: coords.value.longitude
        }
        console.log(coords);
    })
   </script>
```

Comment: Just go to useGeolocation() function and check out what it is using. Maybe you should enable your geolocation on your device?

Comment: Geo api is asynchronous, it's expected that it may be not available on mounted. This not specific to the composable, but it uses Infinity as default value. Depends on how you want it to work, you don't handle errors there, while you possibly should. You could use directly navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition if you want a value once. Composables are for reactivity, which you don't use here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because geolocation is async it takes time to update its value. you can use the watch to set your reactive form variable. here is the code.

```
<script setup>
import {onMounted, ref, watch} from "vue";
import {useGeolocation} from "@vueuse/core";

const {coords, locatedAt, error, resume, pause} = useGeolocation();

const form = ref({
    coords: null,
})

onMounted(() => {
    setGeolocationCoords()
})

const setGeolocationCoords = async () => {
    if (coords.value?.latitude !== Infinity) {
        form.value.coords = {
            latitude: coords.value.latitude,
            longitude: coords.value.longitude
        }
        
        console.log(coords.value)
    }
}

watch(() => coords.value.latitude, () => {
    setGeolocationCoords()
})
</script>
```

you can see the coords object in the console now.